# ASP.Net Identity sign-out all sessions

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

How do you sign-out all sessions with ASP.NET Identity?
Lets say you are signed-in from two different browser with the same user. When the user signs-out from one browser, the session of the other browser should be invalidated as well.
(I need this to invalided all sessions of a user on password change.)

You can sign-out the current session with ASP.Net Identity with the following code.

```
var AutheticationManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
```

This will not sign-out all sessions of a user.

Edit:
The idea with the session was a good starting point. I solved the problem and wrote a [blog post](http://timmlotter.com/blog/asp-net-identity-invalidate-all-sessions-on-securitystamp-update/) in case you have the same problem.

Comment: better post your solution here as an another answer, your blog post not well enough for reading because of poor formatting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding a newly created session from the Global.asax in a list.

Iterate afterwards to compare the user and SignOut the user's sessions.

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyGlobalObject.Sessions.Add(HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication);
}
```

And later, in the signout event:

```
private void SignoutAll()
{
    foreach (var authenticationManager in MyGlobalObject.Sessions)
    {
        authenticationManager.SignOut();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `MyGlobalObject`?

Comment: An object you create to store the sessions in so you can enumerate them